# How to have multiple versions of Ruby AND Rails, and their combinations on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

Since Windows doesn't support rvm (Ruby version Manager), how do we have

- Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.8
- Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.0.0
- Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.0

on the same PC?  Virtual machines can be used but it is kind of troublesome.

Answer (score 68):

Use [uru](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru). It is a multi-platform ruby environment manager. You can download the Windows version here: https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru/wiki/Downloads

**Install the tool**

Assuming `C:\tools` is on PATH and `uru_rt.exe` was extracted to `C:\tools`

```
C:\tools>uru_rt admin install
```

This adds `uru.bat` file to the tools directory.

**Register ruby**

```
uru admin add C:\ruby200\bin
```

**List available rubies**

```
uru ls
174         : jruby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392) 2013-05-16 2390d3b on Java HotSpot(TM)
200p255     : ruby 2.0.0p255 (2013-07-07 revision 41812) [i686-linux]
=> system   : ruby 2.1.0dev (2013-07-06 trunk 41808) [i686-linux]
```

**Switch ruby version**

```
uru 174
---> Now using jruby 1.7.4 tagged as `174`
```

More commands can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru/wiki/Examples

---

## Old answer

I use [Pik](http://github.com/vertiginous/pik) to manage multiple versions of ruby on a Windows machine.

Install the pik gem

```
> gem install pik
Successfully installed pik-0.2.6
1 gem installed
```

Install pik to a location that’s in your path, but someplace other than your ruby\bin dir.

```
>echo %path%
PATH=c:\pik;c:\ruby\Ruby187\bin;

>pik_install C:\pik
Thank you for using pik.

Installing to C:\pik
pik is installed
```

Install Ruby 1.9.2 using RubyInstaller and add the new Ruby version to `pik` registry.

```
>pik add C:\Ruby192\bin
```

List the available Ruby versions:

```
>pik list
187: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i386-mingw32] *
192: ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]
```

To switch to Ruby 1.9.2:

```
>pik 192
>pik list
187: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i386-mingw32]
192: ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32] *
```

To switch between different versions of Rails:

In Rails 2.x, set the RAILS_GEM_VERSION in `config/environment.rb` file:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '= 2.3.8' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

In rails 3, use the `Gemfile` to specify the Rails version:

```
gem "rails", "3.0.0"
```

Comment: Newer version of pik found [here](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik). Different devkits for 2.0 and 2.0-x64 make this solution not work.

Comment: The link to the `pik` in the answer points to the official location.

Comment: @rogerdpack YES! You will want to follow Luis' recommendations: https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/issues/148 and maybe https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/issues/138

Comment: 2014 pik is outdated now there is no use for it

Comment: @JohnnyDerp - Yes, the github page clearly says that it is outdated, i.e no longer maintained. https://github.com/vertiginous/pik . The page suggests that we try Uru as an alternative. Last update for Uru was 5 hours ago. https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru. One of the downsides of free software I guess.

Comment: @HarishShetty - Pik is gone. Can you please add Uru to your answer ?

Comment: @sidsmith, `pik` was retired in this [commit](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/commit/13e5cc2d0a78d821e7c5d4255e86f6a9ca7f24fc). I didn't see the announcement till today. Thanks for  notifying and I am glad that there is a replacement for `pik`.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote myself a little batch file which creates a junction (aka symlinks) on the NTFS.
The idea is to keep the PATH untouched. The path always contains `c:\devkit\bin;c:\ruby\bin;...`. The following Batch file changes the links to the actual directories.

```
@echo off
echo 1 - Ruby 1.9.3
echo 2 - Ruby 2.0.0 (32 bit)
echo 3 - Ruby 2.0.0 (64 bit)
choice /C 123 /M "Which Ruby? "

if errorlevel 255 goto confused
if errorlevel 3 goto 3
if errorlevel 2 goto 2
if errorlevel 1 goto 1
if errorlevel 0 goto 0
goto confused

:1
if exist c:\ruby rmdir c:\ruby
if exist c:\devkit rmdir c:\devkit
mklink /j c:\ruby c:\ruby193
mklink /j c:\devkit c:\devkit-4.5.2
goto end

:2
if exist c:\ruby rmdir c:\ruby
if exist c:\devkit rmdir c:\devkit
mklink /j c:\ruby c:\ruby2-x86
mklink /j c:\devkit c:\devkit-x64
goto end

:3
if exist c:\ruby rmdir c:\ruby
if exist c:\devkit rmdir c:\devkit
mklink /j c:\ruby c:\ruby2-x64
mklink /j c:\devkit c:\devkit-x64
goto end

:confused
echo I'm confused ...

:end
ruby -v
```

Comment: I liked this and one-upped it for you.  However, shouldn't "if errorlevel 255 goto 255" be "if errorlevel 255 goto confused"?

Answer (score 1):

From what I could tell, uru only manages versions of RUBY.

For versions of RAILS, where you've already 2 or more versions on your local maching, to open a project in one's development environment, using an older version of rails, you enter the following in the command window:

rails _3.2.11_ s

where 3.2.11 represents the version of RAILS you want it to use, 
which you want to be the same version as listed in your project's file:

Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

After installing and registering all your ruby installations with [uru](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru), you'll need to install [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) for each of the ruby versions installed. For installation follow these [instructions](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit).

I generally store the DevKit next to the version of Ruby to which it belongs, for example, `C:\Ruby\Ruby193\DevKit` where Ruby193 is the folder containing the 193 version of Ruby that I registered with `uru`.