# How to upgrade Ruby to 2.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-upgrade

My ruby version is

```
ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15) [i386-mingw32]
```

and I am running under Windows 8 with mingw installed.

How can I upgrade it to ruby 2.0 ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) let you play with and manage multiple versions and flavours of ruby on on your Windows box. I have chosen this way because I'm not sure that everything I need will work on the first try with the new version, hence I want also to keep prior versions.

The installation is also simple: if you haven't jet *Pik* [see topic: "Install pik using rubygems"](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik)  then "pik install ruby 2.0.0"

for example:

### Before

```
C:\Sites>pik list
  160: jruby 1.6.0 (ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 330) (2011-03-15 f3b6154) (Java H...
  165: jruby 1.6.5.1 (ruby-1.9.2-p312) (2012-01-25 fffffff) (Java HotSpot(T...
  167: jruby 1.6.7 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-02-22 3e82bc8) (Java HotSpot(TM)...
  187: ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]
  192: ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]
* 193: ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
```

### Install

```
C:\Sites>pik install ruby 2.0.0
** Downloading:  http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/76807/ruby-2.0.0-p0-i386-
mingw32.7z
...
```

### After installation

```
C:\Sites>pik list
  160: jruby 1.6.0 (ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 330) (2011-03-15 f3b6154) (Java H...
  165: jruby 1.6.5.1 (ruby-1.9.2-p312) (2012-01-25 fffffff) (Java HotSpot(T...
  167: jruby 1.6.7 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-02-22 3e82bc8) (Java HotSpot(TM)...
  187: ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]
  192: ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]
* 193: ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
  200: ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24) [i386-mingw32]
```

## Now we can use version 2.0.0

```
C:\Sites>pik use 200

C:\Sites>ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24) [i386-mingw32]
```

## Wondering where the hell are the Ruby folders

```
 C:\>echo %HOME%
 C:\Users\rondinif

 C:\>where ruby 
 C:\Users\rondinif\.pik\rubies\Ruby-200-p0\bin\ruby.exe

 C:\>pik use 193
 C:\>where ruby 
 C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe

 C:\>pik use 167
 C:\>where ruby 
     INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
 C:\>where jruby
 C:\Users\rondinif\.pik\rubies\JRuby-167\bin\jruby
```

and so on...

Comment: Wonderful. I followed the instruction and now I am tasting the latest ruby. Thank you!

Comment: There is another problem. When I run irb, it gives me this error, DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle

Comment: @Znatz I'm glad this works for you so you can accept my answer :-) ..Please see also the answer I Gave to [“DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15601984/1657028) question.

Comment: Well, `pik install ruby`, `pik config installs` and `pik config downloads` shows errors, but rest I used `pik add LOCATION` and everything worked very easily, so +1

Comment: @FrancoRondini I install ruby 2.0.0 using pik, but I am wondering, where is the folder Ruby 2.0? I need that for config.yml in devkit. Thanks

Comment: @catwoman have a look to your %HOME%\.pik\rubies\Ruby-200-p0\ or something like that; please see the last "edit" to the answer

Comment: Pik is no longer maintained: https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/commit/13e5cc2d0a78d821e7c5d4255e86f6a9ca7f24fc

Answer (score 4):

Just install ruby version 2.0 from the official [rubyinstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) site.

There's nothing like 'upgrade'. You can actually run both versions on ur PC at the same time (many people prefer that too). Also refer to this question: [How to have multiple versions of Ruby AND Rails, and their combinations on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648744/how-to-have-multiple-versions-of-ruby-and-rails-and-their-combinations-on-windo)

Answer (score 2):

Well you could just try building it from source, just like how you installed 1.9.3. Personally I would recommend using something like [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) or better still doing Ruby development inside a Linux VM.