# Railsinstaller 3.2.0 with ruby 2.2.3 on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rvm, railsinstaller-windows

I am installing rails through railsinstaller 3.2.0.exe file on my window but with this file I got ruby version 2.2.4 and i need ruby version 2.2.3.

Is it possible to change the ruby or rails version with railsinstaller package?

Comment: Any particular reason for choosing 2.2.3 over 2.2.4 ? Can you not install multiple rubies (one that comes with railsinstaller, and the other your preferred one), and simply use the one you need ?

Comment: 1) my application is built in ruby 2.2.3 2) can you show me the way to install ruby 2.2.3 with ruby 2.2.4(multiple ruby install)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648744/how-to-have-multiple-versions-of-ruby-and-rails-and-their-combinations-on-windo. Try using uru for windows.

Comment: Thank you so much Sam :) It worked with uru :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)