# How to add new Ruby environment in URU?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I can register already installed a Ruby environment to [URU](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru) by following command in terminal:

```
uru admin add c:\ruby-2.2\bin
```

But, What is the way to install another ruby version in URU along existing one?

Comment: Download ruby version and register them http://www.neverletdown.net/2015/08/managing-multiple-ruby-versions-with-uru.html

Comment: @MihalkoFarhat Yes, you're right. Please write an answer with some explanation about new ruby install to separate folder and add this environment to URU. Then, I can accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `rubyinstaller` to install specific version of ruby. After install was completed, you will have some version of ruby. You know the destination of them.

To add already installed but not registered version of ruby:

```
uru admin add SOME_PATH/../bin
```

Good [article](http://rubyonwindowsguides.github.io/book/ch02-03.html) about `rubyinstaller` and `uru`.

Rubyinstaller [downloads](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).

Uru [examples](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru/wiki/Examples).

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648744/how-to-have-multiple-versions-of-ruby-and-rails-and-their-combinations-on-windo) on SO.